Laravel: (Job dispatch) Failed to open stream: Permission denied
fopen(app/storage/framework/cache/data/6a/e8/6ae8f7a027ae2ffc516a3933fcade51ab014d34d): Failed to open stream: Permission denied
Stack trace
app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Bootstrap/HandleExceptions.php:256
app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Filesystem/LockableFile.php:69
app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Filesystem/LockableFile.php:42
app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Cache/FileStore.php:108
app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Cache/FileLock.php:14
app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Cache/Lock.php:91
app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Bus/UniqueLock.php:43
app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Bus/PendingDispatch.php:164
app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Bus/PendingDispatch.php:188
app/vendor/ssntpl/cloud-storage/src/CloudStorageAdapter.php:65
app/vendor/ssntpl/cloud-storage/src/CloudStorageAdapter.php:151

I am dispatching job app/vendor/ssntpl/cloud-storage/src/CloudStorageAdapter.php:65
job
SyncFileJob::dispatch($path, $fromDisk, $remoteDisk)->onConnection($this->connection)->onQueue($this->queue);

then sometimes that line throw above error(Failed to open stream: Permission denied) whereas sometimes it working fine.
can anyone explain me, why is it happened?
what will be the solution for it?
If there was a permission issue then not a single job would be run.
queue connection is sync

I think in your case laravel is using the file cache driver, which stores cached data in the storage/framework/cache/data directory. if it's possible switch from file to redis or database in config/cache.php
however you can fix this with running this command for directory permission
chmod -R 775 storage
and then run
chown -R www-data:www-data storage  //replace www-data with your web server's user.
Clear cache and restart queue workers and try again
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan queue:restart

Its related to permissions,
if you are using linux,you can write in terminal:
sudo chmod 777 -r {directory-address}

if it's related to permission so why was some jobs working fine

are they in the same directories?

fopen(app/storage/framework/cache/data/6a/e8/6ae8f7a027ae2ffc516a3933fcade51ab014d34d): Failed to open stream: Permission denied
app/storage/framework/cache/data/6a/e8/6ae8f7a027ae2ffc516a3933fcade51ab014d34d
above is cache directory and all cache related data store inside cache data directory and other directories inside data was created by laravel itself and they have necessary permissions.

If you have tried what I've said,after entering the command,please write 'php artisan cache:clear' command to purge all cahes

directory permissions also depend on the owner of the directory, @AbhishekSharma it could be that your are running your app as different users from cli vs webserver

@krisgjika ok you are right but why was same job working fine sometimes.
If I check the ratio of success and failure job is 7:3
3 jobs were fail out of 10.

@AbhishekSharma without much context I would guess you write to cache as one user, and later try to read as another user, somehow both users are allowed to write to framework/cache, but can't read something written by the other user. you can ls -la the folders within your cache and see for differences on their permissions and owners
